# Why do we need 2 nodes for opsceneter

Tags: opscenter

Is there any merit in setting up 2 nodes for Opscenter with its own storage  on a virtual environment?
 I am thinking 1 node is good but for H/A does having a second node help?

Thanks,
Vik

Comment: `but for H/A does having a second node help`  Without a second node, your entire system is down if the one-and-only node goes down.

Answer (score 0):

OpsCenter supports automatic failover in an active/passive configuration, but does not support an active/active configuration today.  You can read more about this functionality and how to best shared OpsCenter settings storage between the two instances: http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/configure/configFailover.html